# Error: "Values must match the following regular expression"

Tags: regex, youtube-api

I'm playing with the Youtube Analytics API Explorer and I have no problem until I try to put several metrics in the "Metrics" field.

They ask especifically to enter data in this format

> A comma-separated list of YouTube Analytics metrics, such as views or likes,dislikes.

So I try with this:

> views, likes, shares

But then I get this message:

> "Invalid value 'shares,+ comments+'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[0-9a-zA-Z,]+'"

What am I doing wrong? :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have spaces between the items.  Look at their example:

```
likes,dislikes
```

So you need to do:

```
views,likes,shares
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was just the problem :)